# Latex: What causes this indent

Tags: pdftex

I have the following latex code:

```
% Preamble
% ---
\documentclass{article}

% Packages
% ---
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

    \title{Electronics Equations}
    \author{Tyler Hilbert}
    \date{}
    \maketitle

    \subsection*{Electronic Formula Wheel}
    \includegraphics[width=50mm]{FormulaWheel.png}

    \subsection*{Equations from "Fundamentals of Electric Circuits"}
    % TODO - double check for all equations in chapter 1&2

    Current: $I = dQ/dt$ \smallbreak
    Note: This can also be written like this: $I = \Delta Q / \Delta t$
    %TODO - add Kirchoffs law 
    \bigskip

    Charge: $Q = \int_{to}^{t} i dt$
    \bigskip

    Voltage: $V = dw/dQ$ 
    \bigskip

    Power: $p = dw/dt$ 
    %TODO - check if I should add "Note that: $\sum{p} = 0$"
    \bigskip

\end{document}
```

When I build my file it looks like this:[image]

I am wondering what causes the indentation after the Current line (the line the starts with "Note: This can....." and so forth.  How can I go about fixing this so the indentations is consistent?

Comment: Why do you use `break` if you want a `skip`?

Comment: Because I wanted the "Note: This can..." to be on the next line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want neither `\smallbreak` (that tells LaTeX a page break is nice at the spot) nor `\bigskip`:

```
% Preamble
% ---
\documentclass{article}

% Packages
% ---
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\title{Electronics Equations}
\author{Tyler Hilbert}
\date{}
\maketitle

\subsection*{Electronic Formula Wheel}
\includegraphics[width=50mm]{example-image}

\subsection*{Equations from ``Fundamentals of Electric Circuits''}
% TODO - double check for all equations in chapter 1&2

Current: $I = dQ/dt$\\*[\smallskipamount]
Note: This can also be written like this: $I = \Delta Q / \Delta t$\\*[\bigskipamount]
%TODO - add Kirchoffs law 
Charge: $Q = \int_{to}^{t} i\,dt$\\*[\bigskipamount]
Voltage: $V = dw/dQ$\\*[\bigskipamount]
Power: $p = dw/dt$ 
%TODO - check if I should add "Note that: $\sum{p} = 0$"

\bigskip

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that opening quotes should be typed ``` `` ``` and closing quotes `''`. I also added the customary `\,` in front of the differential.

Answer (score 0):

By default latex indents new paragraphs. Add `\parindent0pt` to your preamble to remove this.